# How to refine types in function that takes union of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, flowtype

There is some function that delegate job to other functions depending of the type of the input array. How can I point out that particular array has to be processed by particular function?

I've been thinking about it and searching for several hours, but couldn't find a solution.

```
type nameType = {
  name: string,
}

type surnameType = {
  surname: string
};

type inputType = nameType[] | surnameType[];

function processSurnames(suranmes: surnameType[]) {
  let result = {};
  // do something with surnames
  return result;
}

function processNames(names: nameType[]) {
  let result = {};
  // do something with names
  return result;
}

function process(input: inputType) {
  if (typeof input[0].name === 'string') { // <--- this refinement doesn't work
    return processNames(input);
  } else {
    return processSurnames(input);
  }
}
```

[the code on flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAdghgWwgFXNAvFA3gKCrRCALigGdgAnASxgHMAaHAXxx1EjIFcL4lUPMufKW69iZSjVrMA3K3bQaYTsH4YCfNAG0AulAA+XHoTW65OAGacYAY2BUA9jChgKDmxFKkAyqMKkAChEKOBgkUhJgsVMdAEpsPCgAGwhgKApPTiS0wSY5fAB6AqgAEwcyByRgAAspKAB3KhqjMVJEjOBRdMzsuRZLaztHZ1d3T1IAOX8A1pJo7TiE-BS0jJFsqFz8qCLS8tJK1Nq6BqbqjU921K61rOA+1itbeycXNw8vAKUVEm-VNHiQigVAsUACCgcoL+WgADDoAHRiTboTAAcnI1DoqMBO2KAB4ALREqA1KikboWGgQJAwNJlTwwVFpeoOCgAa0S+A6XVGH0m0z+sW2TCgECSpGgQK51x4bzGXl8xnCXxgymAQsSLCYQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to refine based on the types of items in an array.

This is because [array access is unsafe](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-array-access-is-unsafe) -- it is always possible for array access to return `undefined`. Refinements can be made with anything other than an array.

I've rewritten your example wrapping the arrays in objects and refining based the "type" property.

```
// ...

type Names = { type: "names", list: nameType[] }
type Surnames = { type: "surnames", list: surnameType[] }

// ...

export function process(input: Names | Surnames) {
  if (input.type === "names") {
    return processNames(input.list)
  } else {
    return processSurnames(input.list)
  }
}
```

[Here is the try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAdghgWwgFXNAvFA3gKCrRCALigGdgAnASxgHMAaHAXxx1EjIFcL4lUPMufKW69iZSjVrMA3K3bQAcoVJRBUBSQBEY0lvpQANlXIkx-CAG0AulBYKoAZVEq12DWm0ieK-UZPAJN7maDZ28mhQNGCcwBZuykiqAD5OLkmsAGacMADGwFQA9jBQYBSFuRCkpM4+SQAU3nAwSUHpKKHWAJTYeEYQwFAUVZyGg4JMcvgA9NNQACaFZIVIwAAWUlAA7lTrXHVVfcPAokMjY3IsONl5BcWl5ZXViVX1umaEFjY9Qv2DwyIxm4sJM+rMFktSCsBhs6NtdmsCBl8MdTgDRsBLlkcvkiiUyhUqqR6tFYiRSXE0D8+lRMlASTAYsAAHQOdDsqA6Xw-KDggA8AFohRoNqphpkaBAkDBBosqjAAOSDLaFCgAaz6KIGpwJT1IL2JFOZxnIXSmdigEEMpGgvy1Jx4D0J1VqugZTONATNfRYTCAA).

Unfortunate :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)?
What does it mean doesnt't work? Have you checked what typeof input[0].name returns?

Comment: _1. Have you tried instanceof?_ I have no prototype to compare with, because I work with response from api. _2. What does it mean doesnt't work?_ It means that flow throws an error: Cannot call `processNames` with `input` bound to `names` because property `surname` is missing in `nameType`. _3. Have you checked what typeof input[0].name returns?_ Yes I did, it returns string.